# How to store an ES6 module in more than one file?

Tags: es6-modules

This declares an ES6 module:

```
<script type="module" src="animals.js"></script>
```

My problem is: this makes a 1-to-1 connection between a module and a source file.

I would like to split "animals.js" into "dogs.js" and "cats.js". Is this possible with ES6 modules?

I would like to define the module in this way:

```
<script type="module" name="animals" src="dogs.js" src="cat.js"></script>
```

Comment: Import cats.js, dogs.js to animals.js, then (named) export them

Comment: @muka.gergely having a module "animals" makes no sense, if it requires the modules "dogs" and "cats" and does not contain anything else but "dogs" and "cats".

Comment: it does make importing all of them easier, or you could use it as an “á la carte” method on deciding which one to import. And also, you can make changes inside animals.js, without the need to update your imports in your other modules. I would call it bundling, if bundling didn’t have an other meaning in this context.

Answer (score 2):

ES modules are constraint to a single exporting context which happens to correlate to a single automatically created exporting context per file. So you can’t. You can however introduce a new module and it will be its own file/script block.

Alternatively, you can use a bundler that will accept several input files and produce a single ES module output file. Webpack might be a great choice.

Alternatively, you can introduce a module that imports and exports the contents of the other modules, serving as a kind of a wrapper or facade if you will.

Also, keep in mind that 1-to-1 connection between a script file and an ES module is inherent to the whole design of the ES modules, as well as many other bundling and namespacing systems. This is legitimately a feature and the need to have more than one source file per module might designate a flawed architectural design in your software.

If you would like a Java-like module behavior, you should definitely check out [Typescript namespaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html). Although, you will eventually realize how many different type inference caveats and parallel module visibility issues are there and thus will stop using them altogether in favor of ES2015 modules, they might be useful for just getting used to the modern technology.

Comment: Sorry but it is common Java practice to put every class in its own file. I can not see any "flawed architectural design" in that practice. And a module makes only sense, if it contains more than one class.

Comment: @ceving lol no, you see, in ECMAScript a term of "module" denotes a concept having absolutely nothing to do with the modules in Java (or whatever this thing you `import` is called). It's in the same way that in Swift a concept of "module" denotes a thing conceptually separate from modules in Java, OR ECMAScript, for that matter. All these languages are completely different and what is considered an obvious practice in Java does not count as a proper way to do in JS. And this thing you are trying to achieve is usually done with usage of bundlers, such as the webpack.

Comment: I would say the ES6 module system is half-assed, if the lack of expressiveness requires bundlers. But it is good to know that it is fine to ignore them.

Comment: @ceving yeah, somehow I supposed your Java background wouldn't allow you to appreciate it

Comment: @ceving I updated the answer with a bit about typescript